# Problem in access image file from outside of script folder

Tags: php, html

Problem: Hard to synchronise image between 2 folder

My project has 2 image folder:

```
Home/user/public_html/image

Home/user/m.fruit.com/image
```

public_html serves the main page for desktop version

m.fruit.com serves the mobile page

Both version serves the same images.

When I have new fruit image, I need to put it into both folder. This becomes double work...

my way of accessing image for desktop version is: (index.php in public_html folder)

```
 <img id="image" src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg">
```

my way of accessing image for mobile version is: (index.php in m.fruit.com folder)

```
 <img id="image" src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg">
```

For mobile version, I did try to access image in public_html so that I don't need 2 image folder. But it seems like not possible:

```
   <img id="image" src="public_html/image/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg">
```

Is there any way to use only 1 image folder to serves these 2 version of website instead of 2 in this case?

Other better solution also welcomed.

Comment: why not make the desktop and mobile site as the same site?

Comment: from www `<img src="http://localhost:<m port>/image">`

Comment: You can also redirect url on .htaccess

Comment: @Meghan how to put 2 index.php of 2 version in 1 site??

Comment: i was saying don't. just make one site. or do what my 2nd comment said

Comment: you can access you images by url path 
For mobile version,
   <img id="image" src="http://www.example.com/image/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg">  
and same you can use for website also on desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can set base URL: like

```
  define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/');
```

then set image src:

```
 <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>image/imagename.jpg ">
```

or create a helper function: 
PHP CODE

```
function asset(path){
   return BASE_URL . path;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
 <img src="<?php echo asset('image/imagename.jpg'); ?> ">
```

This will work on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the image url scheme with this

```
<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

define base_url();

```
  define('base_url', 'http://Home/user');
```

and then call this base url where you want show image.

```
 <img id="image" src="image/<?php echo base_url('/public_html/').$image; ?>">
```